# PDO Prepare used in a function

Tags: php

My sql request doesn't work if I use a function paramater to choice the column.
My goal is to have one function for all request.
Thanks in advance.

```
    $dbh = Connection::getPdo();
    try {
                $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT users_id, nom, prenom, password, role, email, users_login FROM users where ? = ? ');
                $value="'".$value."'";

                $sth->execute(array($parameter,$value));

                $data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $user = new Users();
                $user->setUserFromArray($data);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("ERROR: Could not able to execute query " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting the value in quotes? It's changing the value that it's looking for. Quotes are unnecessary since parameter binding will securely pass the values.

Comment: Why do you catch an exception and then `die`? That's a horrible practice that leaks sensitive information to the user. Please do not catch exceptions if you have no intention of recovering from them

Comment: You can't substitute a column name with a placeholder.

Comment: Many thanks all for yours helps.